# Is there a reason to use the ICU plural syntax for locales without plurals?

Tags: unicode, internationalization, globalization, icu

I noticed that a few locales have only one form of (cardinal) plural defined by the [CLDR](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html). Here are a few examples of popular languages without plurals:

- [Chinese](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#zh)
- [Indonesian](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#id)
- [Japanese](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#ja)

Supposing the following English ICU message string:

`You have {count, plural, =0 {no unread messages} one {# unread message} other {# unread messages}}.`

Is there any value in translating the plural ICU syntax to these languages? For example in Chinese:

**Plural Syntax** `您有{count, plural, other {#}}條未讀消息。`

Or since there is no plural, should we recommend translators to simply use the variable instead like this:

**Variable Syntax** `您有{count}條未讀消息。`

I tested two libraries ([GlobalizeJs](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize) and [FormatJs](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs)) and both seem to work with both syntaxes.

Is there any known issue in interchanging these syntaxes?

Would it be safe for most libraries to recommend using the **variable syntax** for locales without plurals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no value to keep the plural marker. The `=0` case should say 沒有, though.

Comment: you are right my example used the negative form instead of `0`. Do you know by any chance if using the negative form Chinese is considered to increase fluency? I'm working on a tool to help linguist master the ICU syntax and this type of information could be quite useful.

Comment: Actually following up on my question here since its a different topic: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/34968/is-it-more-natural-to-express-0-with-a-negative-form

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years late but please note that there is huge value depending on whether the phrase only uses plural categories or also uses overrides (like the =0 in your example) and whether you are only trying to be grammatically correct in each language or rather trying to sound like a human and not like a machine.

Also, if it’s a matter of teaching linguists how to use ICU, you’re better off explaining how arguments work because it’s not limited to plurals (there’s also selects which have a similar way of working).

Finally, if you are working with translation files such as YML with ICU in them, I would say it’s best to keep the ICU plural marker. This means you can change the source language of your translations at any point in time (including to a language that doesn’t have plurals like chinese), and you won’t have to rewrite all strings that should have kept the plural marker in the first place.